# CreateProcess Running jar with parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, jar, createprocess

I'm trying to start an jar file with additional parameters. The start of the jar works fine but it complains that the parameter is empty.
The parameter -d expects an directory.

I've got this:

```
CString sParameters;

sParameters.Format("C:\\Java\\bin\\java.exe -jar \"D:\\test\\myprog.jar\" -d \"D:\\testdir\"");

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

HANDLE h = CreateFileA(_T("error.log"),
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    &sa,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
BOOL ret2 = FALSE;
DWORD flags = CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE;

ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.wShowWindow = SW_NORMAL;
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.hStdInput = NULL;
si.hStdError = h;
si.hStdOutput = h;


if (CreateProcessA(NULL, sParameters.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, flags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == false)
{

}


CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

CloseHandle(h);
```

In the output log is this output:

Illegal option: '-d D:\testdir', 'd' requires a value

So how must the parameter string be build?

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), there is no `-d` parameter for `java.exe`, but even if there were, you are passing it in the `[arguments]` portion of the command line instead of in the `[options]` portion

Comment: @Remy: the -d Parameter is for the java programm in the jar, so it must be in the arguments portion. And so it works, see my own answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, now it works without an change.
The paramstring looks the same as before:

"C:\Java\bin\java.exe -jar \"D:\test\myprog.jar\" -d \"D:\testdir\""